# How can I trace drools rule execution in KIE server?

Tags: drools, drools-guvnor, drools-kie-server, drools-kie-workbench

How can I enable rule engine tracing/logging when the rule application is running on KIE server?

The rule application was created in the Workbench, and contains no custom code. I am able to execute the rules using the KIE REST API, but the rule app is not producing the expected results.

**Environment:**

Win7

Tomcat 9

Drools 6.5.0-Final

**Update:**

I have tried the following steps:

1. Clone the workbench project locally using git
2. Add logback.xml to the project's root directory
3. Push changes back to the workbench git repo
4. Added logback as a dependency in the workbench Project Editor view
5. Update project version and redeploy to the container

When I do this, it ignores my logging settings, but spams log messages endlessly to the console, telling me that it can't instantiate logback classes:

```
20-Jun-2017 16:58:29.070 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-5] org.kie.server.services.drools.DroolsKieServerExtension.createContainer Unable to create instance of type ch.qos.logback.classic.selector.C
ontextSelector due to ch.qos.logback.classic.selector.ContextSelector
20-Jun-2017 16:58:29.083 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-5] org.kie.server.services.drools.DroolsKieServerExtension.createContainer Unable to create instance of type ch.qos.logback.classic.selector.C
ontextJNDISelector due to ch.qos.logback.classic.selector.ContextJNDISelector
20-Jun-2017 16:58:29.101 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-5] org.kie.server.services.drools.DroolsKieServerExtension.createContainer Unable to create instance of type ch.qos.logback.classic.selector.D
efaultContextSelector due to ch.qos.logback.classic.selector.DefaultContextSelector
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following jars to tomcat's `/lib` folder:

```
 logback-classic-1.1.3.jar
 logback-core-1.1.3.jar
 slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar
 slf4j-ext-1.7.2.jar
```

(Can't remember if the slf4j jars were already there, or if I added them.)

For Windows, create a text file `bin/setenv.bat` if none exists.

In `setenv.bat`, add the following settings:

```
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dlogback.statusListenerClass=ch.qos.logback.core.status.OnConsoleStatusListener -Dlogback.configurationFile="%CATALINA_HOME%\conf\logback.groovy""
```

These console listener instructs logback to tell you if your logback config is wrong. The other setting is the location of your logback config file.

For tracing rules, my `logback.groovy` looks something like this:

```
import java.nio.charset.Charset

appender('STDOUT', ConsoleAppender) {
    encoder(PatternLayoutEncoder) {
        charset = Charset.forName('UTF-8')

        pattern = "%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %logger{5} - %msg%n"
    }
}

appender('STDOUT-SHORT', ConsoleAppender) {
    encoder(PatternLayoutEncoder) {
        charset = Charset.forName('UTF-8')

        pattern = "%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} - %msg%n"
    }
}

root(WARN, ["STDOUT"])

logger("org.apache", WARN, ["STDOUT"], false)
logger("org.kie.server", WARN, ["STDOUT"], false)
logger("org.kie.server.controller", DEBUG, ["STDOUT"], false)
logger("org.guvnor.common.services.builder.IncrementalBuilderExecutorManagerFactoryImpl", ERROR, ["STDOUT"], false)
logger("bitronix", ERROR, ["STDOUT"], false)

logger("org.kie.api.event.rule", TRACE, ["STDOUT"], false)
logger("org.drools.core", TRACE, ["STDOUT-SHORT"], false)
logger("org.uberfire.commons.async.SimpleAsyncExecutorService", ERROR, ["STDOUT"], false)
```

These settings produce spammy and cryptic but useful output from the KIE Server and the Workbench.